# How to pass argument from UI to graphql to fetch data

Tags: angular, typescript, graphql, apollo

I have a graphQl url where I am able to fetch data from the backend.
However, the issue is currently I am providing the hardcoded id of a customer to fetch data.
I want to create an input box and then allow the user to fetch any customer record by entering the customer Id.
Current Hardcoded code to fetch record of Customer:

```
ngOnInit() {
this.apollo
.watchQuery({
  query: gql`
    {
      findCustomer(id: "UF2aLa1L687") {
        id
        customerType
      }
    }
  `,
})
.valueChanges.subscribe(result => {
  this.customer = result.data ;
  this.loading = result.loading;
  this.error = result.errors;
  console.log('Customer Info', this.customer);
  console.log('Loading', this.loading);
  console.log('Error', this.error);

});
```

}

How do I pass value from UI,I need something similar to angular two way binding using ngModel.
I tried this code but I am getting Unterminated String error.

```
  searchByCustomerIdGraphQL() {
console.log(this.customerIdValue);
this.isLoadingResults = true;
this.apollo.watchQuery({
  query: gql`
  {
    findCustomer(id : "` + this.customerIdValue + `") {
      id
    }
  }
  }`
}).valueChanges.subscribe( result => {
  this.customerSearchRecord = result.data;
  this.loading = result.loading;
  this.error = result.errors;
});
}
```

Can someone help me figure out how to pass values?